# Google Map Displays BAD

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hey guys i have an app and a form where i ask the user to put the address and below the textfield i show the google map with a marker where he can drag/drop the marker to correct location. The problem is that at the begining when the map is shown, it is showen just partialy not full of it, and the moment i resize the window the map shows correct. Below are the pictures what i am getting:

First picture the moment i open the form (bad-one):
[image: Bad GoogleMap visualization]

Then after i resize my window(Good-one)

[image: Google map good visualization]

Does anyone have any ide how to fix this??? I wopuld really apruciate it.

Just in case you are wondering the code where i show my map is this:

```
  <div id="address">
    <table>     
        <tr>
              <td align="left" style="width:100%">
              <input type="text" id="addresspicker_map">
              </td>
        </tr>               
        <tr>
              <td style="width:100%">
                <div id="map"></div>
                <div id="legend">You can drag and drop the marker to the correct location</div>
              </td>
        </tr>                                         
   </table>                                 
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

The CSS for the map is this:

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a {font-size: 12px;}
/* Layout helpers
----------------------------------*/
.ui-helper-hidden { display: block; }
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible { position: absolute !important; clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); clip: rect(1px,1px,1px,1px); }
.ui-helper-reset { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: 0; line-height: 1.3; text-decoration: none; font-size: 100%; list-style: none; }

/* workarounds */
* html .ui-autocomplete { width:1px; } /* without this, the menu expands to 100% in IE6 */
.ui-menu {list-style:none;padding: 2px;margin: 0;display:block;float: left;}
.ui-menu .ui-menu {margin-top: 0px;}
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item {width: 100%;}
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a {text-decoration:none;display:block;padding:.2em;}

/* Component containers
----------------------------------*/
.ui-widget { font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 100%; }
.ui-widget-content { border: 2px solid rgba(0,143,15,0.3); background: #ffffff; color: #222222; }

/* Interaction states
----------------------------------*/
.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus { border: 1px solid #ffffff; background: #dadada; font-weight: normal; color: #212121; }

#map {border: 5px solid #DDD; width:95%;  height: 400px;  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;  -webkit-box-shadow: #AAA 0px 0px 15px;}
```

And jQuery 1.10.2

and

```
echo $this->Html->script('jquery-1.10.2.js');
  //THESE ARE JUST FOR GOOGLE MAPS API
  echo $this->Html->script('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false');
  echo $this->Html->script('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js');  
  echo $this->Html->script('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js');
```

And The JavaScript is this:

```
(function( $, undefined ) {

  $.widget( "ui.addresspicker", {
    options: {
        appendAddressString: "",
        draggableMarker: true,
        regionBias: null,
        componentsFilter:'',
        updateCallback: null,
        reverseGeocode: true,
        autocomplete: 'default',
        mapOptions: {
            zoom: 5,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(46, 2),
            scrollwheel: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        },
        elements: {
            map: false,
            lat: false,
            lng: false,
            street_number: false,
            route: false,
            locality: false,
            administrative_area_level_2: false,
            administrative_area_level_1: false,
            country: false,
            postal_code: false,
            type: false

        },
        autocomplete: '' // could be autocomplete: "bootstrap" to use bootstrap typeahead autocomplete instead of jQueryUI
    },

    marker: function() {
      return this.gmarker;
    },

    map: function() {
      return this.gmap;
    },

    updatePosition: function() {
      this._updatePosition(this.gmarker.getPosition());
    },

    reloadPosition: function() {
      this.gmarker.setVisible(true);
      this.gmarker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat.val, this.lng.val));
      this.gmap.setCenter(this.gmarker.getPosition());
    },

    selected: function() {
      return this.selectedResult;
    },
    _mapped: {},
    _create: function() {
      var self = this;
      this.geocoder = {
        geocode: function(options, callback)
        {
          jQuery.ajax({
            url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?" + jQuery.param(options) + '&sensor=false',
            type: "GET",
            success: function(data) {
              callback(data.results, data.status);
            }
          });
        }
        //new google.maps.Geocoder();
      };

      if (this.options.autocomplete === 'bootstrap') {
          this.element.typeahead({
            source: function(query, process) {
                self._mapped = {};
                var response = function(results) {
                    var labels = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        self._mapped[results[i].label] = results[i];
                        labels.push(results[i].label);
                    }
                    process(labels);
                };
                var request = {term: query};
                self._geocode(request, response);
            },
            updater: function(item) {
                var ui = {item: self._mapped[item]}
                self._focusAddress(null, ui);
                self._selectAddress(null, ui);
                return item;
            }
          });
      } else {
        this.element.autocomplete($.extend({
            source: $.proxy(this._geocode, this),
            focus:  $.proxy(this._focusAddress, this),
            select: $.proxy(this._selectAddress, this)
        }), this.options.autocomplete);
      }

      this.lat      = $(this.options.elements.lat);
      this.lng      = $(this.options.elements.lng);
      this.street_number = $(this.options.elements.street_number);
      this.route = $(this.options.elements.route);
      this.locality = $(this.options.elements.locality);
      this.administrative_area_level_2 = $(this.options.elements.administrative_area_level_2);
      this.administrative_area_level_1 = $(this.options.elements.administrative_area_level_1);
      this.country  = $(this.options.elements.country);
      this.postal_code = $(this.options.elements.postal_code);
      this.type     = $(this.options.elements.type);
      if (this.options.elements.map) {
        this.mapElement = $(this.options.elements.map);
        this._initMap();
      }
    },

    _initMap: function() {
      if (this.lat && this.lat.val()) {
        this.options.mapOptions.center = new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat.val(), this.lng.val());
      }

      this.gmap = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement[0], this.options.mapOptions);
      this.gmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: this.options.mapOptions.center,
        map:this.gmap,
        draggable: this.options.draggableMarker});
      google.maps.event.addListener(this.gmarker, 'dragend', $.proxy(this._markerMoved, this));
      this.gmarker.setVisible(false);
    },

    _updatePosition: function(location) {
      if (this.lat) {
        this.lat.val(location.lat());
      }
      if (this.lng) {
        this.lng.val(location.lng());
      }
    },

    _addressParts: {street_number: null, route: null, locality: null,
                    administrative_area_level_2: null, administrative_area_level_1: null,
                    country: null, postal_code:null, type: null},

    _updateAddressParts: function(geocodeResult){

      parsedResult = this._parseGeocodeResult(geocodeResult);

      for (addressPart in this._addressParts){
        if (this[addressPart]){
          if (parsedResult[addressPart] !== false){
            this[addressPart].val(parsedResult[addressPart]);
          } else {
            this[addressPart].val('');
          }
        }
      }
    },

    _updateAddressPartsViaReverseGeocode: function(location){
      this.geocoder.geocode({'latlng': location.lat() + "," + location.lng()}, $.proxy(function(results, status){
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){

          this._updateAddressParts(results[0]);
          this.element.val(results[0].formatted_address);
          this.selectedResult = results[0];

          if (this.options.updateCallback) {
            this.options.updateCallback(this.selectedResult, this._parseGeocodeResult(this.selectedResult));
          }
        }
      }, this));
    },

    _parseGeocodeResult: function(geocodeResult){

      var parsed = {lat: geocodeResult.geometry.location.lat,
        lng: geocodeResult.geometry.location.lng};

      for (var addressPart in this._addressParts){
        parsed[addressPart] = this._findInfo(geocodeResult, addressPart);
      }

      parsed.type = geocodeResult.types[0];

      return parsed;
    },

    _markerMoved: function() {
      this._updatePosition(this.gmarker.getPosition());

      if (this.options.reverseGeocode){
        this._updateAddressPartsViaReverseGeocode(this.gmarker.getPosition());
      }
    },

    // Autocomplete source method: fill its suggests with google geocoder results
    _geocode: function(request, response) {
        var address = request.term, self = this;
        this.geocoder.geocode({
          'address': address + this.options.appendAddressString,
          'region': this.options.regionBias,
          'components': this.options.componentsFilter
        }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                  result = results[i]
                  g = result.geometry
                  g.location = new google.maps.LatLng(g.location.lat, g.location.lng);
                  g.viewport = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                    new google.maps.LatLng(g.viewport.southwest.lat, g.viewport.southwest.lng),
                    new google.maps.LatLng(g.viewport.northeast.lat, g.viewport.northeast.lng)
                  )
                  result.label =  results[i].formatted_address;
                }
            }
            response(results);
        })
    },

    _findInfo: function(result, type) {
      for (var i = 0; i < result.address_components.length; i++) {
        var component = result.address_components[i];
        if (component.types.indexOf(type) !=-1) {
          return component.long_name;
        }
      }
      return false;
    },

    _focusAddress: function(event, ui) {
      var address = ui.item;
      if (!address) {
        return;
      }
      if (this.gmarker) {
        this.gmarker.setPosition(address.geometry.location);
        this.gmarker.setVisible(true);
        this.gmap.fitBounds(address.geometry.viewport);
      }

      this._updatePosition(address.geometry.location);

      this._updateAddressParts(address);

    },

    _selectAddress: function(event, ui) {
      this.selectedResult = ui.item;
      if (this.options.updateCallback) {
        this.options.updateCallback(this.selectedResult, this._parseGeocodeResult(this.selectedResult));
      }
    }
  });

  $.extend( $.ui.addresspicker, {
    version: "@VERSION"
  });

  // make IE think it doesn't suck
  if(!Array.indexOf){
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj){
      for(var i=0; i<this.length; i++){
        if(this[i]==obj){
          return i;
        }
      }
      return -1;
    }
  }

})( jQuery );
```

And This is How i inicialise the Map

```
    <script>
  $(function() {
    var addresspicker = $( "#addresspicker" ).addresspicker({
      componentsFilter: 'country:IT'
    });
    var addresspickerMap = $( "#addresspicker_map" ).addresspicker({
      regionBias: "it",
      updateCallback: showCallback,
      mapOptions: {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(46, 2),
        scrollwheel: true, // if false means u can zoom only with the +, - sign
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      },
      elements: {
        map:      "#map",
        lat:      "#lat",
        lng:      "#lng",
        street_number: '#street_number',
        route: '#route',
        locality: '#locality',
        administrative_area_level_2: '#administrative_area_level_2',
        administrative_area_level_1: '#administrative_area_level_1',
        country:  '#country',
        postal_code: '#postal_code',
        type:    '#type'
      }
    });

    var gmarker = addresspickerMap.addresspicker( "marker");
    gmarker.setVisible(true);
    addresspickerMap.addresspicker( "updatePosition");


    function showCallback(geocodeResult, parsedGeocodeResult){
      $('#callback_result').text(JSON.stringify(parsedGeocodeResult, null, 4));
    }
    // Update zoom field
    var map = $("#addresspicker_map").addresspicker("map");
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function(){
      $('#zoom').val(map.getZoom());
    });

  });
  </script>
```

The point is that the  map is inside a table which has some styling. if i put the map outside the table it works just fine but inside it, its a problem...

Comment: How are you loading the maps (good and bad) into the div? Presumably there's some javascript you can share with us.  Any relevant CSS might be useful too

Comment: @duncan Above is the code neccesary for the googlemap to work properly

Answer (score 0):

Try to call

`google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');`

after page load and after each window/document resize.